# Edit structure tool for mustache file in Intellij IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, mustache, intellij-plugin

Having opened the Intellij IDEA mustash file, I want to open its structure (Structure tool). And the Handlebars tab is always selected first, not HTML tab.
This is very annoying.
Is there a way to make HTML tab autoselected?
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b07rL.png)

Comment: Can you right click on the tab and select `Focus on Startup` (or something similar)?

Comment: no way, this can't be configured

Comment: Is this the plugin you are using? - https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6884-handlebars-mustache

Comment: @ryanwebjackson Yes, it is.